# Debug help - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

My program compiles correctly but I get the same message when I try and run it:

> Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` error on my calendar program

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package displaycalendars;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class DisplayCalendars {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar
            (Integer.valueOf(args[1]),
            Integer.valueOf(args[0])-1,1);

    printHeader(calendar);
    printData(calendar);            
  }

  public static void printHeader(Calendar calendar){

    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;

    String monthName = "";

    switch(month){
      case 1: monthName="January";
        break;
      case 2: monthName="February";
        break;
      case 3: monthName="March";
        break;
      case 4: monthName="April";
        break;
      case 5: monthName="May";
        break;
      case 6: monthName="June";
        break;
      case 7: monthName="July";
        break;
      case 8: monthName="August";
        break;
      case 9: monthName="September";
        break;
      case 10: monthName="October";
        break;
      case 11: monthName="November";
        break;
      case 12: monthName="December";
        break;
    }

    System.out.println(" "+monthName+ ", " +calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    System.out.println("Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");
  }

  public static void printData(Calendar calendar){
    int dayinWeek=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    for (int i = 1; i< (dayinWeek); i++)
    {
      System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <
        (Calendar.DATE); i++){
      System.out.print("\n");
      calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    }
    System.out.printf("%4d",calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
  }
}
```

Comment: The `main` method expects arguments. Are you providing them?

Comment: @Marvin Probably not since the code doesn't contain any other arrays.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Check the **stacktrace** provided along the error message. It is pointing to the line where you write

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar
        (Integer.valueOf(args[1]),
        Integer.valueOf(args[0]) - 1, 1);
```

An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown whenever you try to **access an array** at an index outside of its bounds. That means if the an array contains, let's say, `6` elements and you access the `7`-th element. Or if you try to access the element number `-1` (which of course does not exist). From its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an **illegal index**. The index is either **negative** or **greater than or equal** to the **size** of the array.

In your case you are accessing

```
args[1]
// and
args[0]
```

and you get an exception since `args` does not contain an element at index `0` nor at index `1`. It's **probably empty**. You can check this by using `args.length` like

```
System.out.println("The size is: " + args.length);
```

---

### Command-line arguments

The `args` argument of a `main` method is automatically created by the **JVM** and the machine passes arguments you have provided at creation of your application, so called **command-line arguments**.

This is usually inside your **console** where you started the app with some kind of

```
java DisplayCalendars
```

command. You can then pass arguments like

```
java DisplayCalendars firstArgument secondArgument
```

After that the JVM automatically assigns `args` with the given arguments:

```
args[0] => firstArgument
args[1] => secondArgument
```

If you use an **IDE** you can probably also set some command-line arguments, somewhere in the settings (in Eclipse it's inside the *run configuration* settings).

More on this at the [official Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).